# FCM with Prase-server hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, parse-server

I want to send notification from one-user to other app users. I'm planning to achieve this using FCM.
I'm new with PARSE-SERVER & FCM. I want to know how can I use FCM for push notification with self hosted parse-server on AWS EC2. Any proper guideline how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This guide is what you're looking for. Parse-Server is pretty well documented, you should use that documentation as your first resource, and come to SO when you need to ask clarifying questions, showing us what you've tried that isn't working.

http://docs.parseplatform.org/tutorials/android-push-notifications/